# C++ Hexadecimal Multiplication Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, calculator

**Let me first start by saying I do not have access to debuggers and I'm using Nano as my editor**

Currently, with my calculator, I am beating my head against a brick wall(segmentation fault). I've tried going through my pointers to discover what my problem is, but my lack of experience/knowledge has only gotten me so far. Let me explain what works so far in my program. Currently, I am able to store hexadecimal numbers in a linked list and add them together. The problem comes from my multiplication method.Somehow leftNode is becoming NULL midway through the multiplication method throwing a segmentation fault. I'm wondering at what point does leftNode become NULL?

**Multiplication Method:**

```
LList Calculator::multiply(LList& left, LList& right) {
    LList prodSum;
    listnode *leftNode = (left.next());
    int zeros = 0;
    for(;;) {
        if(leftNode == NULL) break;
        int lval = leftNode->data;
        LList curList;
        for(int i = 0; i < zeros; i++) {
            curList.insertTail(0);
        }
        right.reset();
        listnode *rightNode = (right.next());
        int carry = 0;
        while(rightNode != NULL) {
            int rval = rightNode->data;
            int product = lval * rval + carry;
            carry = product / 16;
            product %= 16;
            curList.insertTail(product);
            rightNode = (right.next());
        }
        while(carry) {
            curList.insertTail(carry % 16);
            carry /= 16;
        }
        prodSum = *add(prodSum, curList);
        leftNode = (left.next()); // eventually causes a segmentation fault
        leftNode->data << endl;
        ++zeros;
    }

    return prodSum;
}
```

**Classes related to multiplication:**

```
class listnode {
    public:
        element data;
        listnode * next;
};

class LList {
    private:
        listnode * head;
        listnode * tail;
        listnode * view;

    public:
        LList();
        ~LList();
        void read();
        listnode* next();
        void reset();
        void print();
        void insertTail(element val);
        void clean();

        element deleteHead();
};

class Calculator {
    public:
        Calculator();
        //inline LList* add(LList& left, LList& right); works
        inline LList multiply(LList& left, LList& right);
};

Calculator::Calculator() {

};
```

**Other methods related to traversing nodes:**

```
listnode* LList::next() {
    listnode* temp = view;
    if(temp != NULL)
        view = view->next;

    if(view == NULL) {
    }
    return temp;
};

void LList::reset() {
    view = head;
}


LList::LList(){
    head = NULL;
    view = NULL;
};

void LList::insertTail(element val) {
    listnode * temp;
    temp = new listnode;
    temp -> data = val;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        view = head;
    }
    else
        tail -> next = temp;
    tail = temp;
};

void LList::clean() {
    while(head != NULL)
        deleteHead();
};

element LList::deleteHead() {
    listnode * temp;
    temp = head;
    head = head -> next;
    delete temp;
    return temp -> data;
};

LList::~LList(){
    delete head;
};
```

Comment: What problem? What is your question?

Comment: Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my multiplication function?

Comment: *I do not have access to debuggers* -- So how are you going to write anything non-trivial?  Are you going to run the program "in your head" to look for mistakes?  Or do you expect to write programs perfectly the first time, and never need to have to debug them?  Get yourself a debugger.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961466/c-hexadecimal-calculator-multiplication

Comment: @Xarotic Because you have at least one bug. The process of creating a [MCVE] might help you find it; it would certainly lead to a better question.

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes I asked this question but have since changed some code, I was under the impression that I was to ask another question than revise the other one.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What I'm trying to say is that I am using a very simple editor and with very little more than syntax highlighting. I am not using this editor out of choice, but because of a requirement. I am still in the early stages of learning c++ and don't want to get spoiled with IDE's like Visual studios.

Comment: This is insane.  So you're writing a non-trivial C++ program, and because of "spoilage of Visual Studio", you don't want to learn to use the tool that every programmer learns, and that is the debugger?  Also, a debugger exists for every environment that is out there.  So saying you don't have one -- I bet you do have one, probably `gdb` if the compiler used is gcc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have absolutely no knowledge of using debuggers in c++, or the environment I'm required to work in for the program. It's not that I'm opposed to learning debugging techniques. I think I have narrowed down why I'm getting the segmentation fault, its because this line 'leftNode = (left.next());', I'm just unsure of how it's becoming NULL

Comment: But to get to that stage, how are you going to follow your code unless you step through it with a debugger?  That line is just where everything finally falls apart -- it isn't the source of the issue.  To find that, the code has to be debugged.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well I guess that's the answer to this question then. I guess I need to go research debuggers. Thank you. I was using a modified version of the multiplication method from the last post, and trying to adapt it to fit the rest of my code. I guess the real flaw here is my knowledge of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's me again.

One exception occurs after the line you marked: `// eventually causes a segmentation fault`, there seems to be a partially-formed line for sending `leftNode->data` to `cout`, but on the final iteration through left's nodes, `leftNode = (left.next());` will set `leftNode` to NULL, so a dereference here might be causing the fault.

One other problem is that no copy constructor or assignment operator is defined for LList, so this line: `prodSum = *add(prodSum, curList);` will give prodSum a set of list nodes that will be deleted right after.

However, LList's destructor only seems to delete the head node, not the whole list, so there's a grab-bag of invalid and valid going on.

Also, multiply returns prodSum, so the lack of a copy constructor will make something similar happen.

I'm including a version of your code that seems to work.  I had to make my own `add` function, just because I don't see it here.

I made the destructor delete all of the LList's nodes.

I marked the default copy constructor and assignment operator `=delete` because the default implementations do the wrong thing.

In order to pass LList objects around by value, I added a move constructor and a move assignment operator.  These pass allocated nodes from one object to another, and only one object is allowed to keep one set of nodes, so you don't have to worry about double-destruction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef int element;

class listnode {
    public:
        element data;
        listnode * next;
};

class LList {
        listnode *head, *tail, *view;
    public:
        LList() { head = view = tail = NULL; }
        LList(LList&& src) : head(src.head), tail(src.tail), view(src.view) { src.head = src.tail = src.view = nullptr; }
        LList(const LList&) = delete;
        ~LList() { clean(); }
        LList& operator = (LList&& src) {
            clean();
            /* OK here */
            head = src.head;
            tail = src.tail;
            view = src.view;
            src.head = src.tail = src.view = nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        LList& operator = (const LList&) = delete;
        listnode* next() {
            listnode* temp = view;
            if(temp) view = view->next;
            return temp;
        }
        void reset() { view = head; }
        void print();
        void insertTail(element val) {
            listnode* temp = new listnode;
            temp->data = val;
            temp->next = NULL;

            if(!head) { view = head = temp; }
            else      { tail->next = temp;  }
            tail = temp;
        }
        void clean() { while(head) deleteHead(); }

        element deleteHead() {
            listnode*  temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            const element data = temp->data;
            delete temp;
            return data;
        }
};

LList add(LList& left, LList& right) {
    LList sum;
    int carry = 0;
    left.reset();
    right.reset();
    for(;;) {
        const listnode* leftNode = left.next();
        const listnode* rightNode = right.next();
        if(!leftNode && !rightNode) break;
        if(leftNode) carry += leftNode->data;
        if(rightNode) carry += rightNode->data;
        sum.insertTail(carry % 16);
        carry /= 16;
    }
    if(carry) sum.insertTail(carry);
    return sum;
}

LList multiply(LList& left, LList& right) {
    LList prodSum;
    listnode *leftNode = left.next();
    int zeros = 0;
    for(;;) {
        if(!leftNode) break;
        int lval = leftNode->data;
        LList curList;
        for(int i = 0; i < zeros; i++) {
            curList.insertTail(0);
        }
        right.reset();
        listnode *rightNode = right.next();
        int carry = 0;
        while(rightNode) {
            int rval = rightNode->data;
            int product = lval * rval + carry;
            carry = product / 16;
            product %= 16;
            curList.insertTail(product);
            rightNode = right.next();
        }
        while(carry) {
            curList.insertTail(carry % 16);
            carry /= 16;
        }
        prodSum = add(prodSum, curList);
        leftNode = left.next(); // eventually causes a segmentation fault
        //std::cout << leftNode->data << std::endl;
        ++zeros;
    }
    return prodSum;
}

LList string_to_list(std::string hex_string) {
    LList list;
    for(size_t i=hex_string.length()-1; i+1; --i) {
        char c = hex_string[i] | 0x20;
        if     (c >= '0' && c <= '9') list.insertTail(c - '0');
        else if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') list.insertTail(c - 'a' + 10);
    }
    return list;
}

std::string list_to_string(LList& list) {
    std::string hex_string;
    list.reset();
    for(;;) {
        listnode* node = list.next();
        if(!node) return hex_string;
        static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
        hex_string = digits[node->data] + hex_string;
    }
}

int main() {
    //LList list = string_to_list("1234aBcd");
    //std::string s = list_to_string(list);
    //std::cout << s << '\n';

    LList left = string_to_list("111");
    LList right = string_to_list("333");
    LList prod = multiply(left, right);
    std::cout << list_to_string(prod) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: My savior! Thanks again friend.

Comment: *I marked the default copy constructor and assignment operator =delete because the default implementations do the wrong thing.*  -- All you need to do is write the copy constructor, and the assignment operator can be implemented using copy / swap.  I already mentioned this in the comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961466/c-hexadecimal-calculator-multiplication)

Comment: @Xarotic I forgot to mention someting about this line: `prodSum = *add(prodSum, curList);`  If `add` is returning a pointer value which needs to be deleted, you will lose the pointer's value and end up leaking memory.  Also, a pointer's object's value is an lvalue, so you will need to add Paul's brilliant copy constructor to make that work at all, because I only added what was required to make my example work.

Comment: @Xarotic In that last comment, I meant Paul's copy assignment operator, which requires an existing copy constructor.